# Retrieving the name of the current function in PHP

Tags: php, function

Is there a function that can return the name of the current function a program is executing?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Yes, you can get the function's name with the magic constant [`__FUNCTION__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
class foo
{
  function print_func()
  {
            echo __FUNCTION__;
  }
  function print_method()
  {
            echo __METHOD__;
  }
}

$obj = new foo();
$obj->print_func();      // Returns: print_func
$obj->print_method();    // Returns: foo::print_method
```

Answer (score 17):

Maybe via debug_backtrace http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: -1 - magic constants are proper way to do this.

Comment: Why did this get so many downvotes, its a valid way of doing it, just not the preferred method.

Comment: Good developing isn't making it work, it's doing it correctly. But I wouldn't downvote, I would simply refrain from upvoting.

Comment: only **`debug_backtrace()`** works correctly, when function is included in other functions too..

Comment: @SBoss good development isn't doing it "correctly" - that's subjective. Good development is making it work according to a requirement (usually an issue in the issue tracker with details on what's needed to be done). Without knowing what's the task at hand - `debug_backtrace` and `magic constants` are equally "correct". He could be writing a test case and `debug_backtrace` might actually be a better fit for all we know. :)