# Vim and php: how can I know which function I'm in?

Tags: php, vim, vim-plugin

is there any plugin or other stuff to know in which function I am currently in?

For example: let's say I have a function called my_long_function($arg1, $arg2) 400 lines of code long; I'm in the middle of it (so I can't actually see the name): is it possible to display the name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the name of the current function in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115913/retrieving-the-name-of-the-current-function-in-php)

Comment: if your functions are 400 lines long - you're looking to solve the wrong problem

Comment: @JackManey Not a duplicate; the asker is looking for a vim plugin, while that duplicate does not mention vim

Comment: In normal mode type: `?function\s` - then ctrl-o to return to your originating position.

Comment: @AD7six ok, but that's not the point. I'm working on code written by other people. 400 lines was just to say...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this plugin:

```
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3197
```

If your functions are 400 lines long, this appears like it can help. You may want to refactor some code though, so as to not have such long functions.