# Base_Controller: Access current controller name in Laravel

Tags: controller, laravel, laravel-3

I am trying to get the current controller name in my base controller in Laravel 3.2 but it returns null. Within my Home Controller there's no problem.

How can I get this value within my `Base_Controller`?

```
<?php

class Base_Controller extends Controller {

    public $page_data = array();


    public function __call($method, $parameters) {
        return Response::error('404');
    }


    public function __construct() {


        $this->page_data['body_id'] = Request::$route->controller;


        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the get_called_class() if you have PHP 5.3 available so that you can get the controllers class name? It is a workaround though and not exactly what you were looking for...

Comment: Awesome thanks! is theres anyway to have the controller action too?

Comment: Sure, check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115913/retrieving-the-name-of-the-current-function-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115913/retrieving-the-name-of-the-current-function-in-php)