# CakePHP get action name

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, action

In CakePHP, it is possible to get the called function string using the

```
$this->action
```

syntax. It returns the literal string of whatever is called, so if the URL is `/do_this`, it returns `do_this`, and if it's `doThis` it'll return `doThis`. Regardless of the called method's real name.

What I am looking for, on the other hand, is the called method's actual name, no matter the URL syntax.

Is there a way to find it out?

I'd preferably be able to do this in the `beforeFilter` method.

Comment: Its the structure of cakephp's clean url that whatever you write in url that action is called. for example www.domain.com/x/y will call  y action in x controller. This is defined in your .htaccess file.

Comment: It would help if you'd explain the actual problem that you are trying to solve, ie why exactly do you need the exact method name? ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Perhaps you could get the action and then do `if(method_exists('doThis'))` for each possible case. But agree with ndm, if you clarify your intention there may be a better way. (also see `function_exists`)

Answer (score 26):

You should use the request object.

CakePHP 3.3 and below

```
$this->request->params['action'];
```

Since 3.4

```
$this->request->getParam('action');
```

I think this should contain the real method name that was called. CakePHPs router resolves the string URL to a controller / action pair and other args, all of that ends up in the request object. Read the documentation and do `debug($this->request);` in your beforeFilter() to see what else is there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it also returns the string which was used in the query, and not the function's actual name.

Answer (score 4):

In CakePHP 2 you can use $this->action, in CakePHP 3 you must use $this->request->params['action']

Comment: can you provide references to the some documentation, where this is mentioned? and an example if possible.

Answer (score 4):

The `params` array (CakePHP >= 3.4) is deprecated The correct way to get the current action within a controller is :

```
$currentAction = $this->request->getParam('action');
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this? 
[Retrieving the name of the current function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115913/retrieving-the-name-of-the-current-function-in-php)
This obviously will not work in the beforeFilter. You can set a variable: 
private $action_name in the Controller and set it from within the methods and use it afterwards, in afterFilter

Comment: Unfortunately, that's too late for me. Sorry.

Comment: That is, too late within the runtime. I need to know the function that is about to be called as early as in the beforeFilter function.